# $\phi$ uwo continuous faithful tracial state on a VNA with GNS.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M \subset B(\mathcal{H})$ be a von neumann algebra and $\phi$ be a uwo continuous faithful tracial state. I understand that we obtain the GNS $(\mathcal{H}_\phi, \pi_\phi, \xi_\phi)$ with $\xi_\phi$ the cyclic vector can be shown to be separating and a tracial vector for the image of $\pi_\phi$. From the representation $\pi_\phi$, we have an isomorphism $M \cong \pi_\phi(M)$. Defining $m \xi_\phi \rightarrow m^* \xi$, we can extend this to $\mathcal{H}_\phi$(due to $\xi_\phi$ being a tracial cyclic separating vector) denote this as $J$. We can show that $J^2 = I$, $J$ is conjugate linear, and $M' = JMJ$. This essentially shows that our von neumann algebra is in standard form. We denote $M \xi_\phi$ as $L^\infty(M, \phi)$ and $\mathcal{H}_\phi$ as $L^2(M, \phi)$

Let $N$ be a von neumann subalgebra of $M$. We can restrict our $\phi$ to $N$. From GNS again, we can obtain $L^2(N, \phi|_N)$. Maybe because my algebra is quite weak, I am having trouble understanding why $L^2(N, \phi|_N) \subset L^2(M, \phi)$(since it seems the left cosets seem to be different) and to show that $\xi_\phi$ is cyclic vector(the same cyclic vector for $M$) for $N$ (i.e. $N\xi_\phi$ is dense in $L^2(N, \phi|_N)$. Also, is $\mathcal{H}$ isomorphic to $\mathcal{H}_\phi$? Could someone help me understand the all relationships between these spaces. For context, this is to build up to define the condition expectation projection for the closed subspace $L^2(N, \phi|_N)$.

Comment: The map $x\xi_{\phi|_N} \mapsto x\xi_\phi$ for $x \in N$ can be checked to extend to an isometric embedding of $L^2(N, \phi|_N)$ into $L^2(M, \phi)$, which is what that inclusion means.

Comment: All infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces are isomorphic, so $H \simeq H_\phi$ nearly always holds. I presume that is not what you meant? That you want the isomorphism to carry the action of $M$ on $H$ to the action of $M$ on $H_\phi$? In that case no. While the commutant of $M$ in $B(L^2(M, \phi))$ is $JMJ$, which is finite, the commutant of $M$ in $B(H)$ could be properly infinite. For example, $H = L^2(M, \phi) \otimes l^2$ and $M$ only acts on the first tensor component, then its commutant is $JMJ \otimes B(l^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\phi$ is faithful, the cosets are singletons. And the inner product is the same, so you are taking the inclusion $N\subset M$ and when you complete $M$ in the $\phi$-topology, the closure of $N$ is the completion of $N$ in the same topology. So $L^2(N,\phi)\subset L^2(M,\phi)$ is an actual inclusion.

The cyclic vector $\xi_\phi$ is $1_M$. As $1_N\in M$ is a projection, $$N\,1_M=N\,(1_N+(1_M-1_N))=N\,1_N,$$ so the same $\xi_\phi$ is cyclic and separating for $N$ in $L^2(N,\phi)$.

As for $H_\phi\simeq H$, this is usually true in the sense that for most common cases  they will be infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces. But there is no canonical isomorphism. This can be seen in finite dimension, take $M=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and $\phi$ the normalized trace. Then $M$ acts on $\mathbb C^2$, but $H_\phi=\mathbb C^4$.

Comment: That depends on your definition of "von Neumann algebra" and of  "subalgebra". It is fairly common to consider von Neumann subalgebras with a different unit; the most common case being compressions to a corner, i.e. $N=pMp$ for a projection $p$.

Comment: Since $\phi$ is faithful, then I should just view the inner product space on $M$ i.e. $\langle x, y \rangle = \phi(y^*x)$. Can I find a cyclic vector for $M$, that may not be cyclic for $N$?

Comment: Yes, take $M=M_2(\mathbb C)$ and $N=\mathbb C \oplus\mathbb C$. Then $\xi=[1\  0]^T$ is cyclic for $M$ but not for $N$ (note that $\dim N=2$, while $\dim N\xi=1$).